# ActiveRecord How to verify a record has sucessfully saved on the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-6

I have learned the hard way that

```
model.save
```

will return true only if the record passes validations, If there are any errors adding/updating the model at the database end, it still returns true.
Therefore using

```
 if model.save
       render 'yayy'
 else
       render 'error'
 end
```

Is not reliable.

are there any method that has the same functionality but only returns true if the database successfully updates or otherwise what is the best way to verify that the record has saved successfully on the database.

(if it matters I am using postgres as the database)

Comment: If the database raises an error during the save then that should propagate back to Rails and raise an error there. Are there circumstances where you find this is not the case? See http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save

Comment: Provide a reproducible example/scenario when that happens. And make sure you're not catching errors that should abort a save and cause it to return a false positive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [ActiveRecord::Persistence](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html).

Besides others, there are such methods, as [`new_record?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-new_record-3F) and [`persisted?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-persisted-3F) which you might be looking for.